# MySQL - Error 1064 in Stored Proc SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written the following stored procedure which in HeidiSQL is giving me an **Error 1064** at the line starting with `SET pay_ref = SELECT CONCAT('KOS' ...`

Let me firstly explain what's going on with this procedure. I have a table `gamers` with a BIGINT primary key with auto_increment. This proc is supposed to:

1. Take in some params from the user
2. Check if the user already exists in the db according to his/her email address, and spits back the word "DUPLICATE" if a reord does exist
3. Else it does the insert as normal
4. Then it reads in the ID of the new record created and converts it to a varchar, pads it with leading zeros and then gets concatenated with some other strings
5. This new string (which should read for example `KOS00001ABCDEF`) then gets updated to the `pay_refcode` field >>> this is how we have settled on generating a unique payment reference for the user
6. If all works out well it updates `retval` with the newly generated reference code to be read by PHP script.

---

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `InsertGamer` (
    IN p_fname          VARCHAR(30),
    IN p_lname          VARCHAR(30),
    IN p_email          VARCHAR(255),
    IN p_favgame        VARCHAR(60),
    IN p_pay_suffix     VARCHAR(6),
    OUT retval          VARCHAR(14)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE last_id BIGINT;
    DECLARE pay_ref VARCHAR(14);

    IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM gamers WHERE (email = p_email))) THEN
        SET retval = 'DUPLICATE';
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO gamers (fname, lname, email, favgame, pay_refcode)
        VALUES (p_fname, p_lname, p_email, p_favgame, NULL);
        SET last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        SET pay_ref = SELECT CONCAT('KOS', (SELECT LPAD(CONVERT(last_id, VARCHAR(5)),5,'0')), p_pay_suffix);

        UPDATE gamers
        SET pay_refcode = pay_ref
        WHERE application_id = last_id;

        SET retval = pay_ref;           
    END IF;
END //
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out what the problem is and would sincerely appreciate any help from you.  Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the `SELECT` keyword from line which you set the value for `pay_ref`.

```
SET pay_ref = CONCAT('KOS', LPAD(CONVERT(last_id, CHAR(5)),5,'0'), p_pay_suffix);
```

full code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `InsertGamer` (
    IN p_fname          VARCHAR(30),
    IN p_lname          VARCHAR(30),
    IN p_email          VARCHAR(255),
    IN p_favgame        VARCHAR(60),
    IN p_pay_suffix     VARCHAR(6),
    OUT retval          VARCHAR(14)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE last_id BIGINT;
    DECLARE pay_ref VARCHAR(14);

    SET @count := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gamers WHERE email = p_email)
    IF (@count > 0) THEN
        SET retval = 'DUPLICATE';
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO gamers (fname, lname, email, favgame, pay_refcode)
        VALUES (p_fname, p_lname, p_email, p_favgame, NULL);

        SET last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

        SET pay_ref = CONCAT('KOS', LPAD(CONVERT(last_id, CHAR(5)),5,'0'), p_pay_suffix);

        UPDATE gamers
        SET pay_refcode = pay_ref
        WHERE application_id = last_id;

        SET retval = pay_ref;           
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. I had already tried that to no avail :(

Comment: same error, same place:
....`right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(5)),5,'0'), p_eft_suffix);` ....

Comment: No, it should be `CHAR` not `VARCHAR`. See my answer above

Comment: Yea, I just saw that. Why is that though if I'm casting to the same type that the variable `pay_ref` is declared as?

Comment: Thank you anyway JW! You're a life(and time)saver!